# Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3' in Visual Studio 2015 Nuget package manager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, razor, visual-studio-2015

I tried the following:

1. I am trying to open a code set created in VS 2010 (pluralsight exercise) in VS Community 2015.
2. The System.Web.Mvc reference was showing up with an error due to which the code won't compile. I tried to update the NuGet Microsoft.AspNet.MVC to current version - 5.2.3 and got the below error:

*Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.*

3. I removed the code set and re-tried the above steps and update the NuGets incrementally only till the following and successfully compile the solution.

Microsoft.AspNet.MVC      v4.0.40804

Microsoft.AspNet.Razor    v2.0.30506

Microsoft.AspNet.Webpages v2.0.20710

I would like to know how the NuGets can be updated to their latest stable version.

Comment: You might want to change the target framework of project to lesser than 4.0

Comment: Isn't there any way to move forward? I suppose a framework less than 4.0 can be used but then would be stuck there, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 5.2.3` & `Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3` packages contains only .NET 4.5 assemblies, and hereby can't be installed on any project which has `targetFramework=4.0` in web.config file even they're succeeded to add inside Package Manager Console.

If you're willing to change target framework version, edit `targetFramework` attribute value on both `compilation` & `httpRuntime` element in your project to use .NET 4.5 assemblies, or use project properties => `Application` => `Target framework` => `.NET Framework 4.5`:

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.5">...</compilation>

<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

NB: The latest compatible Razor engine version for `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 4.040804` is [2.0.30506.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Razor/2.0.30506). Unfortunately as of now package's metadata doesn't have any info for supported target frameworks, hence you need to find out which packages fit to your project by yourself.

Related issue:

[Dependencies of .NET Framework (Issue #878)](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/878)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! It worked after I upgraded the target framework to 4.5 and then updated the NuGets after a restarting VS.